# Find all integer solutions to the equation $x^2 − x = y^5 − y$.

Tags: diophantine-equations

My professor gave us a worksheet with diophantine equations including this one he claims that it is one of the easier ones but that it has a unique solution.

Find all integer solutions to the equation $$x^2 − x = y^5 − y$$.

Also my professor will give extra credit for all prime number solutions (x and y).

Comment: If the equation was for $y^2$ instead of $y^5$, we would get that $x + y = 1$.

Comment: Solutions include $y = -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 30$ corresponding to $x = (0,1)$, $(0,1)$, $(0,1)$, $(-5,6)$, $(-15, 16)$, $(-4929,4930)$ respectively.
I suspect those are all, but don't have a proof.  The curve has genus $2$, so by Faltings there should be only finitely many rational points.

Comment: Note that $y^5-y$ is divisible by $5.$  So either $x=5$ or $x\equiv 1\pmod{10}$.  Also, $y^5-y$ is divisible by $3$. So $x=5$ doesn't work, so $x\equiv 1\pmod{30}$.

Answer (score 2):

Rearranging the equation gives
$$(x^2-y^2)-(x-y)=0$$
Now note that $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$.

I'll let you take it from here.

Comment: Sorry it was supposed to be y^5 not y^2

Comment: Well this brings forward that $$(x-y)(x+y -1) = 0$$ so either $x - y = 0$ or $x + y = 1$. I assume that $x$ and $y$ are distinct so we don't consider $x - y = 0$, but if there exist prime number solution pairs $(x, y)$, then this is impossible because given $x$ and $y$ are prime, $x + y\neq 1$. The same applies for all integers $x$ and $y$.